# How can I round this inward-pointing corner?

Tags: bevel

[image: Arcade Machine]

Hey guys, I'm new to Blender. I would like to round the inward-facing corner where the highlighted vertex is (to achieve a smooth "slope") but I am not sure how to achieve this. I've tried bevelling different selections, adding loop cuts and removing the "screen" on the console, all with no luck. Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: bevel should work but it probably needs a work on the topology afterwards

Comment: can you provide your blend file?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys. I tried working on the topology after bevelling and that helped :) It was just a little tedious because I had to drag each new point out separately. Maybe there is an easier way, but at least it looks right now! I attached my blender file with the topology corrected on one side, for reference.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGWpEg9oAY9P-EcaTFzprBgO84Xu9gLH/view?usp=sharing